# How to add a method to the ViewModel and firing the PropertyChanged event from there?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I would need accommodate the scenario where I have something like a timer and want to have changed property values reflected in the UI at one moment in time (basically  I need Update the UI every x seconds).

I need to know how to add a method to the ViewModel and firing the PropertyChanged event from there.

```
   namespace MyClient.Common
    {
        public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, /*[CallerMemberName]*/ String propertyName = null)
            {
                if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

                storage = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
                return true;
            }

            protected void OnPropertyChanged(/*[CallerMemberName]*/ string propertyName = null)
            {
                var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
                if (eventHandler != null)
                {
                    eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }

            public void CallOnPropertyChanged()
            {
               // what to add here?
            }

        }
    }
```

App.xaml.cs

```
namespace MyClientWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {


        private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            App._myDataSource.Load();
            App._myDataSource.CallOnPropertyChanged();
            // I need to rise OnPropertyChanged here
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {


            // timer on the same thread
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(DispatcherTimer_Tick);
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20); // 10 seconds
            dispatcherTimer.Start();

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: For what property do you want to notify?

Comment: Any property, I need to refresh all UI

Comment: make OnPropertyChanged public and call it with a null propertyName. Null is interpreted by WPF as "all properties of this object have changed".

Comment: You can just call the "OnPropertyChanged" in your BindableBase class? If you really want to update properties with a Timer (I would advise against it) you could use some Reflection magic to find all classes of BindableBase, find all properties then call OnPropertyChanged for these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this in your code behind?

```
((TestViewModel)this.DataContext).OnPropertyChanged("PropName");
```

You can call the `OnPropertyChanged();` directly.

But it does seem that there must be a better way of doing what you want to accomplish. I would rather try the advice of @emedbo.